# How to get the checkbox value if readonly and not selected

Tags: php, html

I have several check box

```
foreach ($result as $set){ 
    if ($set['Req']=='0')
    ?><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="1"> 
    <?else?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="1" checked READONLY DISABLED>?>
}
```

> If req!= 0 , the checkbox will be readonly and must checked. If not ,
>   allow the user check or not check

Assume there are four checkbox generated

```
checkbox1 : readonly
checkbox2 : select 
checkbox3 : not select
checkbox4 : readonly
```

Currently the select[] is only {1} because, readonly / not checked will not post the value 
. How to get an select[] which is {1,1,0,1} ? Thank you

**Update:
How can i know which  checkbox is not selected  and add `select[] = 0`  if the user have not check that box?**

One way i can think of is i get the total length of the array =4 in this case,
and i can get it now

But the problem is how can i add it to the correct position?

```
currently i have select[] = {1,1,1} and $len=4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to give each checkbox an explicit index:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select[1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="select[2]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="select[3]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="select[4]" value="1" />
```

And check which indexes are set in the submitted form with `isset`. Unchecked/disabled checkboxes will not appear in the submitted form.

Comment: yeah , it is easier , how can i add a '0' if the item not exist? assume total length = 4 and [1]=>'1' and [3]=>'1' , which means i need to add [2]=>'0' and [4]=>'0' , but how? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the checkboxes, you could do:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="0" style="display:none;">
```

...OR try this...

```
<input onfocus="this.blur();" type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="0">
```

...OR this...

```
//this function returns True if a given field is checked
function isChecked($chkname,$value){
        if(!empty($_POST[$chkname])){
            foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval){
                if($chkval == $value){
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

$checkboxValues = array(
        array('milk','required'),
        array('bread','not-required'),
        array('juice','required')
    );

$submittedValues = array();

foreach($item in $checkboxValues){
    if(isChecked('select', $item)){
        array_push($submittedValues, 1)
    }else{
        array_push($submittedValues, 0)
    }
}
```

In your HTML form...

```
foreach ($checkboxValues as $chkVals){ 
    if ($chkVals[1]=='required')
    ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="<?=$chkVals[0];?>"> 
    <?else?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="<?=$chkVals[0];?>" checked READONLY DISABLED>
        ?>
}
```

In order for this to work, **each option value must be different/unique**.

Comment: This way the user doesn't know what is selected.

Comment: It can, i can display the message

Comment: sorry but this still can not post the value, if check box is unchecked, simply speaking, what i would like to have is : post select[] = 0 when the check box is not checked

Comment: Thank you! since the select[] will not post if not checked, how can i know whether it is checked or not?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="select[1]" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select[1]" value="1" checked readonly> 

    <input type="hidden" name="select[2]" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select[2]" value="1"> 

    <input type="hidden" name="select[3]" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select[3]" value="1" checked readonly>

    <input type="hidden" name="select[4]" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select[4]" value="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to set a hidden field in the form to the values that you want, as disabled fields are not sent in the request.

Comment: yeah but it will mix up the value. for example, i add hidden box 1 for checkbox 1, both name= select[] , the post result will be double